# Oracle script encoding issue: (PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" ...)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

**Script Below:**

```
DECLARE
  V_COLUMN_EXISTS NUMBER := 0;  
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO V_COLUMN_EXISTS
    FROM USER_TAB_COLS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'BILLING_INTEGRATION_PATH'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'ANIMAL_BILLING_SETTINGS';

  IF (V_COLUMN_EXISTS = 0) THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ANIMAL_BILLING_SETTINGS ADD BILLING_INTEGRATION_PATH VARCHAR2(500) NULL';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

**Description:** This run fine if executed alone but gives error when run as batch.

[image: Error]

Comment: Are there other anonymous blocks in the batch script or is this the only script?

Comment: There are other 1485 scripts, this the 1486th, it will execute in sequence. All other runs fine when it came here, it breaks.

Comment: Then you need to see exactly before 1486 if there is a slash `/` missing for the previous script.

Comment: that is not possible, it was running all fine before adding 1486

Comment: no, as far as you know it was *not* all running fine. You might not have had an error if there was a missing /, it just might not have run at all. Please update your question and add in the previous statement from your script.

Comment: previous script....DECLARE V_TABLE_EXISTS NUMBER := 0; 
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO V_TABLE_EXISTS FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TM_TASK_TYPE';
 IF V_TABLE_EXISTS = 1 THEN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TM_TASK_TYPE CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
 END IF;
END;
/

Comment: @All - thanks for support. Not an issue any more. It was reported from my client. I was not getting this in my local oracle setup. It seems it was an encoding issue with client's environment setup which they corrected it.